# How to click on button with class name or tag name with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to click on a button in this picture with class name pdw-v-pill, these are two buttons I want to iterate from these two buttons [please open this image to see HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZOPa.png) I have wrote this but it didnt work.

```
product=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'product-detail-wrap').find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'pdw-meta')
others = product.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'pdw-v-body')
elements = others.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'pdw-v-pill') 
sleep(5)
for e in elements:
 e.click()
```

Comment: _want to click on a button_: Specifically which button do you want to click?

Comment: `find_elements` returns `list`. `list` doesn't have such attribute as `find_element`. If you want to get list of nodes (products) and then get list of descendant nodes (elements) of each product node you need to add `for` loop for products and then inner `for` loop for elements

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get these elements with `pdw-v-pill` you do not need to locate all their parents explicitly.
In case these are only 3 elements on that page with class name `pdw-v-pill` you can get and iterate over these elements as following:

```py
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'pdw-v-pill')
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

In case there are more elements with class name `pdw-v-pill` on the page while 'product-detail-wrap' is a unique locater for parent element for the desired elements you want to access you can use this CSS Selector:

```py
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'. div.product-detail-wrap div.pdw-v-pill')
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

Comment: It is giving me the error below after iterating through only 2 elements, if there are more than two then this error occurs:

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: please help asap